# How can I open Rss feeds from YouTube, Blogspot and Twitter into my app

Tags: iphone, rss, twitter, blogs

I created an Iphone App that gets RSS Feeds from My YouTube Channel, My Blog and My Twitter. I works great except  for when I click on any off the feeds such as one of my videos it takes me to Safari to watch it. Or when I click on one of my blog feeds it takes me to safari and opens my blog. Is their any way that I can have it open within my app so that I do not have to close safari and then re-open my app to view the rest?

Comment: You haven't provided a lot of detail here.  How do you download the RSS feed?  How do you handle links within these feeds?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone will, by default, open URLs in Safari. You can create a UIWebView to display a link in your app.

See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In short, you can create a view controller for your webview, and in the loadView method, do something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the links in a UIWebView instead.